# Appending problematic polygon from File Geodatabase to Oracle ArcSDE using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

I have a File Geodatabase that has some polygons in it. I am using append to copy them to an Oracle SDE 10.2 database. However there are some polygons that when imported have a null value for shape in the SDE. An example is shown below. Why is this happening, why is is valid in the file and not in Oracle, and more importantly, how do I get the polygon in to Oracle?

[image]

The red polygon is from the File Geodatabase, the blue is one previously imported in to Oracle. Below is a close up of the hole / intersection [image]

Comment: Did you run Check Geometry? If so, you might add those results.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/check-geometry.htm

Comment: The vertices look like they've been snapped to a grid, maybe through something that is limiting precision. It might be worth it to go back through the history of the data to see if you can find what's introducing this, instead of fixing just the geometries that have been corrupted to the point of becoming invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Check Geometry, try running repair geometry on your polygons before appending to the SDE:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm

It is happening because Oracle stores a different type of geometry than a file geodatabase. It could be from self intersections, or null geometry. Repair will fix some of this

Comment: Thanks, yes. Check geometry was identifying ring ordering, which repair was able to resolve. I need to check now whether this works for the rest of the dataset.

Comment: This helped tremendously in visualizing data and allowing me to perform operations on the data to improving the odds of successful importing. Combined with the function at https://gist.github.com/mpetroff/5530329 and info from https://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/04/filling-in-holes-with-postgis/ it seems that I'm able to gracefully handle all the source data.